# Replace a line in a file using shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I need to replace a line in from a file using a shell script.

The file is:

```
# cat /root/sge_scripts/night_sched_conf
algorithm default
schedule_interval 0:0:05
maxujobs 12
queue_sort_method seqno
```

I want to replace the third line (after maxujobs) by a value generated in the script.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
#!/bin/sh
export SGE_ROOT=/opt/sge
source=/opt/sge/defalt/common/settings.sh
delete=1
total=`qstat -u "*" | awk ' { print $4 } ' | sort | uniq | wc -l`
total_users=$((total - delete))

case $total_users in

1) range=18;;
2) range=9 ;;
3) range=7 ;;
4) range=6 ;;
5) range=5 ;;
6) range=4 ;;
7) range=3 ;;
8) range=3 ;;
9) range=2 ;;
10) range=2 ;;
11) range=2 ;;
12) range=2 ;;
13) range=1 ;;
14) range=1 ;;
15) range=1 ;;
16) range=1 ;;
18) range=1 ;;
19) range=1 ;;
20) range=1 ;;
21) range=1 ;;
22) range=1 ;;
23) range=1 ;;
24) range=1 ;;
25) range=1 ;;
26) range=1 ;;
27) range=1 ;;
28) range=1 ;;
29) range=1 ;;
30) range=1 ;;
31) range=1 ;;
32) range=1 ;;
33) range=1 ;;
34) range=1 ;;
*) echo "INVALID NUMBER!" ;;
esac

current=`cat /root/sge_scripts/night_sched_conf | awk ' /maxujobs/ { print $2 } '`
if [ "$range" != "$current" ]
then
  sed -i '3s/.*/maxujobs           "$range"/' /root/sge_scripts/night_sched_conf
fi
```

Comment: And the problem is that you get `"$range"` instead of a number?  The shell doesn't expand things inside single quotes, which is good.  It does mean you need to be careful.  Probably `'3s/.*/maxujobs '"$range/"` (which is a single argument, even the the first part is in single quotes and the second part in double quotes).

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is the way to do  it .There is a command in linux called `sed` an stream editor which is used to edit the shell script files like updating the string or replace the string can be done in this.You could follow the below reference and try to replace.Try it out with this command and let me know if you are facing any issues

[Reference](http://www.folkstalk.com/2012/01/sed-command-in-unix-examples.html)

Comment: My impression is that they're aware of `sed`; they show it being used at the bottom of the script.  Methinks they should be able to do better than the case statement, but that's a whole different argument.

Comment: Thanks but i want tp pass range value to sed like sed -i '3s/.*/maxujobs           "$range"/' /root/sge_scripts/night_sched_conf

Comment: Can u show us the exact file changes , so i could help better on this if its not done ..